# C# DataGridView cambiar signo EURO a $

Tags: c#

En una columna de mi datagridview pude editarla para que ésta sea un formato de moneda. El problema que tengo (leí mucho en Google y no encuentre alguna solución) es que me muestra en un formato de moneda que no es la que quiero. Me gustaría poder reemplazarla pero no se como.

A continuación, le dejo la ScreenShot del DataGridView

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán, la columna "Precio" se muestra con el signo de Euro, y yo quiero que se muestre con el signo pesos ($)

Acá les dejo el código, con el cual, implemento esta propiedad.

```
dgvFacturacion.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,#";
dgvFacturacion.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
while (dr.Read())
     {
     dgvFacturacion.Rows.Add(dr["ID Articulo"].ToString(), dr["Articulo"].ToString(), 
     dr["Cantidad"].ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(dr["Precio"].ToString()) , 
     dr["Subtotal"].ToString());
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes establecer el formato del dato de una columna usando la propiedad `Format` desde la propiedad de la columna llamada `DefaultCellStyle`

Por ejemplo para usar formato de monedas en una columna usando tu configuración regional, puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
dgvFacturacion.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c";
```

O por ejemplo usar una cultura específica y números decimales específicos:
(2 Decimales y Símbolo de moneda $)

```
dgvFacturacion.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
dgvFacturacion.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Más información:

[Estándar de Cadenas de formato - Especificador de Formato de Moneda ("C")](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

[Cómo formatear datos en un control DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-format-data-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Excelente! Muchas gracias!